# Using a local html file as the new tab page in firefox

Tags: firefox

I'm using Firefox 44.0 for Windows, and would like to use a html file hosted on the file system as the page that appears on a new tab page - it contains links and other resources that's useful for my workflow.

I'm using the "New Tab Override" plugin for FF which essentially restores the `browser.newtab.url` option. I get my local html file showing when I create a new tab page.

However, the problem is that the path to the file appears in the url bar so that whenever I start typing a url in the url bar (from when I want to go to a known location in the new tab), it's appended to the filepath, instead of replacing it.

Is there another way I can show a local file as a new tab whilst leaving the urlbar blank so I can type urls in when desired?

Answer (score 0):

No sooner than I posted after thinking I'd set it up properly, by changing the newtab.url option from 'home page' to 'custom url' and then entering the path to the html file, the url is highlighted on a new tab open so typing a new url will overwrite the existing location. Sorted!